# Free Web development (HTML, CSS, JS) & D3.js IDE for beginners

Tags: web-development, ide

**OS**: Windows 11

**Type**: IDE, Web Dev & D3.js

**What are you going to do with it?**

Course exercises and if suitable a Narrative Visualization project using D3.js.

**What is it for? How are you going to use it?**

I'm taking CS416 **Data Visualization** at UIUC and the second half of the course covers *integrating data into web pages,
interactive visualizations in web pages, and narrative visualization* using CSS, HTML (DOM, SVG), js, only as minimal prereqs for the major tool, **D3.js**.

**Use**:

1. Major: short, allegedly 15 min, exercises
2. Would be nice: D3.js Narrative visualization project

The exercises can be completed in a tool the professor developed, the DOM tryer-outer, that allows you to see the results of your code when you run a snippet of code.

The problem I ran into with this was writing and running code then seeing nothing happen without being provided any error messages.

I spent a day on one 15 min exercise trying to figure out why it won't run,  while the deadline for a project of substantial weight was looming.  I had to drop the course and lose $2,700 in tuition reimbursement.

The TA suggested Chrome DevTools which was terrifying without any background except about 15min of video lectures on CSS, HTML, and js.

DevTools shows all the HTML, CSS, and js, (as I recall) code to create the Coursera page, which is extensive, while the exercise code is a tiny snippet in an app in the web page.

I didn't even know which window to search, let alone, how to find the relevant code.

**Features**:

1. Guidance and clear, helpful, error messages.
2. See the resulting visualizations and basic shapes created by a snippet easily.
3. IDE code coloring and all the usual IDE features.